# How to nested promise.all

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm using es6 and have the following promises. What i want is the next Promise.all to wait for previous Promise.all to be completed before execute the next one. I have tried with the below codes but it's not working, only Promise 1 is resolved.

```
var deletePromises = [];
arr.menuItems.forEach((item, idx) => {
  if (item.replace) {
     deletePromises.push(deleteFromFirebase(user.uid, item));
  }
});

// Promise 1
Promise.all(deletePromises).then(res1 => {
  var uploadPromises = [],  updateRecordPromises = [];

  arr.menuItems.forEach((item, idx) => {
    uploadPromises.push(uploadToFirebase(user.uid, item));
  });

  // Promise 2
  Promise.all(uploadPromises).then(res2 => {
    arr.menuItems.forEach((item, idx) => {
      item.replace = false;
      updateRecordPromises.push(updateRecord(user.uid, item));
    });

    // Promise 3
    Promise.all(updateRecordPromises).then(res3 => { 
        console.log('All promise execute with successfully');
    });
 });
});
```

**MarkM Answer**

Try to use chaining as Mark suggest but the problem still there. I had found where the problem was, it is uploadPromises that never get resolved and then is never get called.

**uploadToFirebase function**

Stuck here, but the file is successfully  uploaded. I can see all the files.

```
const uploadToFirebase = (userid, item) => {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const uploadUri = Platform.OS === "ios"
      ? RNFetchBlob.wrap(item.pic_url.replace("file://", ""))
     : RNFetchBlob.wrap(item.pic_url);

    Blob.build(uploadUri, {
      type: "image/png;"
    }).then(blob => {
     // upload image using Firebase SDK
    firebase
    .storage()
    .ref("menu_items")
    .child(userid)
    .child(item.new_filename)
    .put(blob, { contentType: "image/png" })
    .then(snapshot => {
      console.log("Promise resolve: ", snapshot);
      resolve(snapshot);
      blob.close();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      reject(error.message);
    });
  });
 });
};
```

**Updated code**

console.log('Print res2') is not printed

```
var deletePromises = [],
uploadPromises = [],
updateRecordPromises = [];

arr.menuItems.forEach((item, idx) => {
  if (item.replace) {
    deletePromises.push(deleteFromFirebase(user.uid, item));
  }
});

Promise.all(deletePromises)
.then(res1 => {
  console.log("Print res1:", res1);
  arr.menuItems.forEach((item, idx) => {
    uploadPromises.push(uploadToFirebase(user.uid, item));
  });

  return Promise.all(uploadPromises);
})
.then(res2 => {
  console.log("Print res2:", res2);
  dispatch({ type: MENU_UPDATE_SUCCESS, payload: arr });
  dispatch(reset("menuItem"));
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log("Print error:", error);
});
```

Comment: `Promise.all` returns a promise which is resolved when all the Promise passed to the promise.all is resolved. So you can just `then` the `Promise.all` call like normal `Promise` flow

Comment: I've trying to debug with console.log in then of promise2 . Seems like it has been resolved completely but not entering then, try to console.log in then of promise2, but nothing was printed. What i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It is because one of menuItems array prop -> new_filename is empty, thats why promise never get resolved. So, i just need to add empty checking for each of item prop and then the promise was resolved properly. Thanks to @MarkM for the answer. Now the code much more cleaner and easier to read compare to the nested promise.

```
Promise.all(deletePromises)
.then(res1 => {
  console.log("Print res1:", res1);
  arr.menuItems.forEach((item, idx) => {
    if (!isEmpty(item.new_filename)) {
      uploadPromises.push(uploadToFirebase(user.uid, item));
    }
  });

  return Promise.all(uploadPromises);
})
.then(res2 => {
  console.log("Print res2:", res2);
  dispatch({ type: MENU_UPDATE_SUCCESS, payload: arr });
  dispatch(reset("menuItem"));
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log("Print error:", error);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to nest the Promises, you can return your new `Promise.all` from `then()`, which will let you chain them. Easier with an example:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

function slowF(i) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(i), i*200)
    })
}
var p = arr.map((i) => slowF(i))


Promise.all(p)
.then((p) => {
    console.log("In first Promise.all resolving: ", p)
    var newP = p.map(i => slowF(i) )
    return Promise.all(newP)   
})
.then((p)=>{
    console.log("In second Promise.all resolving: ", p)
})
.catch((e) => console.log("error: ", e))
```

Comment: And what is i variable inside then block?